# Netlogo simulation how to add gas-station?

Tags: netlogo

I have a smart city simulation project using Netlogo and I need to add a "Turtle Shapes" gas station in the tools but I dont know how can I put it in the street be cause I want the cars that I have in simulation to pass throw and take gasoline my question is how can I add the gas station and calculate the total consomation of gasoline by cars and thanks.

The next image shows the simulation but without gas-station!!
[image]

Comment: I'm not able to make sense of your question. It seems like several questions at once. I'd suggest picking one thing at a time to ask, and try harder to explain that thing clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow really cool project! Basically you can see the gas station as a particular kind of patch, then if a car touch this patch his energy goes up to maximum. The answer now is: how the car knows where is the gas station? You can do something like that: everyone that pass near the gas station leave a scent of knowledge of where the gas station is and if for example a car is half empty fuel then it starts follow the scent where is more strong and arrives at the gas station. I do this for my ant colony in order to make return them to the nest from every point of the map and it works just fine. [Here's my project on github, I just upload it for you](https://github.com/MaxBubblegum47/Squeamish_Ants)

Comment: Thank you verry much i already solved the problem and sorry for the late responce it have been a wile since i was here thank you again